# Function that receives an array and a property, returns an array of property values

Tags: javascript

```
var pluck = function(inputArray, inputProperty){
   var tempString = ""
   var finalArray = []

   for(var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i = i + 1){
        tempString = inputArray[i].inputProperty
        finalArray.push(tempString)
}
log(finalArray)
}
```

tempString on line five is returning null. Is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: It should be `inputArray[i][inputProperty]`

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why it needs brackets instead of a .?

Comment: Because when you use `.` it treats the property name literally, not as a variable.

Comment: Because accessing like `inputArray.0."somevar"` is a TypeError, and accessing as `someobj.prop` treats `prop` as a literal property. Bracket notation is essentially the same as dot notation.

Comment: Thanks again. This stumped me for a while.